# How to turn a simple image with clear edges into a graphic

Tags: shapes, scanning

I have scanned an peace of glass.

I see the edges but if I zoom in then it does not look like a line.

What I need is the edge structure as line which can be turned in to a graphic. I want it to look like it was made by a program and not scanned.

How do I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Hi Sankp, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site! You will also want to mention which program that you intend to work in.

Comment: Hello @AndrewH, I have tried edge detection with gimp, but it looks bad and I don't know how to make a graphic of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple. The best way is to redraw it. Use the photo as a reference.

1. Launch Illustrator.
2. Open the image you just photographer in Illustrator.
3. Lock the layer.
4. Create a rectangle using a Rectangle tool on top of the image same width and height.
5. Goto Filters/Stylize/Rounded Corners and round the rectangle edges to fit the radius of your image shape.
6. using a pen tool create cutout paths for the camera and button.
7. select all shapes and using the Pathfinder tool, Minus the front elements.

That should do it. Oh, and if you're using a different tool, like Gimp, the steps should be very similar (I think).